# Word moving bullet point to the next page VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bulletpoint list. Each bullet point has multiple rows and i want the next bullet point to start from the start of the next page, rather than break the bullet point's text to two pages. Below is the code i have so far:

```
With Selection.Range
.Collapse
.Text = Sometext
.Font.Size = 9.5
End With
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=4
Selection.TypeParagraph 'This usually works, but rather than going down one paragraph, i need to move     to page 2. 
With Selection.Range
 .Collapse
.Text = SometextInPageTwo
```

Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for this? Paragraph formatting can do this very nicely with the *Keep lines together* and *Keep with Next*.

Comment: «*Keep with Next*» would likely not be appropriate in this case, as it would force the bullet point to the next page even if it would fit on the current page.